# Import of Celestial Effects on Satellite Radio Interference

Tags: astronomy, electromagnetic-radiation, interference, radio

Some internet (among other) infrastructure comprises satellites, which beam communications in radio frequencies. These satellites, to ground observers, appear as very small solid angles in the sky.

This makes me wonder if there is significant interference between other skyward radio sources (e.g. stars (incl. sun), CMBR, ionospheric reflections, etc.). These satellites are solar powered, so they can't exactly drown out everything.

I assume one calculates the satellites' orbits sufficiently to aim transmit/receive dishes precisely. But surely this can't ensure that other radio sources don't influence the outcome.

My question is essentially: how much of this makes a practical difference? Do we just aim very carefully? Is there a lot of signal processing error correction that happens? Are the effects just negligible? Do they just transmit on very narrow frequencies, thus producing high intensities with low power? What relative orders of magnitude are interfering signals versus communications signals?

Answer (score 0):

There is considerable noise from celestial sources. Some sources of noise are constant like cosmological microwave background and few are variable like solar winds. Apart from this there is distortion of waves because of magnetosphere present in earth's atmosphere. Linearly polarized waves polarization changes when they pass through magnetosphere making the signal redundant. Circularly polarized waves with anticlockwise rotation as seen from satellite can pass through magnetosphere with little distortion. Coming to noise from other sources, noise from constant sources are simply filtered out. Noise from stars and other celestial sources(except sun) are negligible. Noise due to solar activity is highly variable. When there is peak solar activity the signals are distorted and communication is not feasible. These cases occur rarely. But on an ordinary day the noise due to solar activity can be easily filtered out. Nevertheless heavy signal processing is present.